# What is the purpose of DelegateExecute registry value

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry

When reading through the registry `shell/open` keys, for instance:

```
HKCU\Software\Classes\ms-settings\shell\open
HKCU\Software\Classes\http\shell\open
```

I see the Default key which corresponds to the opening application and the way parameters are passed when it is executed.

Sometimes another value of `DelegateExecute` is also present. What is this value responsible for? 
Also `IsolatedComma` is unclear to me.

What are those keys responsible for?

Comment: I think the delegate execue gives an id of the application to execute

Answer (score 3):

DelegateExecute means the command handler is implemented as a [`IExecuteCommand`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-iexecutecommand) COM object instead of a simple application that is executed. The {...} string is called a GUID and it identifies a specific COM library that implements the required interface which in this case is IExecuteCommand.

People wishing to make their own IExecuteCommand can follow the guide [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100312-01/?p=14623).